# how to rig leg with hydraulic jack

Tags: animation, rigging

im modeling a robot and want to have a hydraulic jack on the back of the leg
how can i rig that?

[image: robot]

[image: i want it to move from how it is on the right to the left]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found  that if you do a copy location and change the Head/Tail value and then add a track to the other side

[image]

Comment: why don't you mark your answer as accepted so people will be more likely to look at it if they have the same problem? :)

Comment: good point i did so now